# Unity - large amount of 2d collider objects with lag

Tags: unity-game-engine

Everybody, I am developing glitter app with unity 3d now.
But, I have a big challenge in development.

[This link is glitter app video on google drive link.](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0BxpS5Ek2uQGLTVl2azdkM3ozT28)

In this app, the challenge is the lag with large amount of glitters.
I designed glitter with simple Sprite and 2d circle collider, rigidbody2d.
I used unity 2d physics engine.

From **800** glitters, app is lagged on modern android device.
How can I solve this challenge? Looking forward to hearing about this challenge.
Regards.

Comment: have you tried swapping the circle colliders for box colliders?

Comment: Detecting collision between circles (radius comparison) is much more easier than detecting box collision (axis-aligned bounding boxes comparison)

Comment: Even if I don't know how you will be able to use and implement it along with the Physics engine of Unity, I suggest you to take a look at Octrees. In few words, you divide your world into smaller sub parts and collision detection between two entities are computed only if these entities are in the same sub part.

Comment: Thanks @turnipinindia. When I use boxcollider2d, it was faster than circle collider2d a little, but It does not make fast effects yet.
I need better way to solve lag issue of many collider2d objects manipulation.

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried to profile the app? Just to know where is the bottle neck.

Comment: Hrusilov has a point, try and run the profiler, maybe it is not the collider that is the problem, the problem might be that you are using a very large source image for the glitter with lots of transparency maybe

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at Particle Emitters ? I believe using too much 2DColliders might be overkill.

Comment: Great Idea. Could you explain me details for me and our developers?
Thanks.